# How can a compiler know which addressing mode to use

Tags: compiler-construction, computer-science

Architectures have different addressing modes, some of which are limited in the amount of displacement they can handle. Imagine an architecture has two instructions:

```
#1 ldw reg, signed imm7(reg) # max displacement = 64 (2^6)

#2 ldw reg, (index-reg, base-reg) # no limit on amount of displacement
```

What I struggle to understand is: how does the compiler choose between these two instructions. More often than not the required displacement is not known before link time.

Does the compiler always take the conservative approach and only use instruction #1 if it known the max displacement? Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Does 1 and 2 use different amount of bytes in machine code after encoding? Sometimes this is solved in linker (`ld`), while compiler just places some special relocation to the instruction (as optimization; can be hard in variable-lenght encoding). In other cases there is default memory model for code like mcmodel in intel compiler (https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/691767 "small - Tells the compiler to restrict code and data to the first 2GB of address space") and compiler knows that code will be limited to 2 GB and may use 32-bit signed displacement; and mcmodel large will use 64-bit disp

Comment: In my case these instructions use the same amount of bytes after encoding.  Using conventions like the intel memory model you describe is a very sensible approach, which I didn't think about. That is in fact the answer to my question. Thank you.